# VBA - IF ElseIf with .Visible = True/False

Tags: vba, ms-access

I was hoping I could get some help on a VBA issue I ran into, but first I would like to say that I am in no way an expert of VBA, or anywhere close to that... But, I am eager to learn!

I am working with reports within MS Access 2010 and using VBA, I am hiding 1 page footer and showing another based on the page number. The problem I am runnning into is that I need to make the footer visble and invsible twice in report. I tried to use an IF ELSEIF, but it does not seem to be working. Does this code look correct? Or am I doing something wrong?

```
If Me.Page <= 2 Then
    Me.PageFooter1.Visible = True
    Me.PageFooter2.Visible = False
ElseIf Me.Page >= 9 Then
    Me.PageFooter1.Visible = True
    Me.PageFooter2.Visible = False
Else
    Me.PageFooter1.Visible = False
    Me.PageFooter2.Visible = True
End If
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: For the love of code, *rename your controls* - how are we supposed to know which of `Text146` or `Label233` is supposed to be what?

Comment: sorry, I have edited the above. Hopefully it makes sense now...

Comment: I hope you've also renamed the controls in your actual code, for the sake of whoever is going to be maintaining it =)

Comment: What's not working exactly?

Comment: Umm..... don't page footers affect the entire report? Is that the problem?

Comment: @RubberDuck - Yes, page footers affect the whole report. But the way DB and report were built, it is not currently possible for me to use Group Footers to acheive the footers.

Comment: @Mat'sMug - The first IF works, Footer1 is visible on pages 1 & 2 and Footer2 is visible on pages >2. But when it comes to the ElseIf for pages >= 9, it does not show Footer1, it still shows Footer 2.

Also, I am deff trying to clean up as much as I can, but I am the 3rd generation to handle this DB, so its not always pretty...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the first two conditions are doing the same thing:

```
If Me.Page <= 2 Then
    Me.PageFooter1.Visible = True
    Me.PageFooter2.Visible = False
ElseIf Me.Page >= 9 Then
    Me.PageFooter1.Visible = True
    Me.PageFooter2.Visible = False
```

Whether the page is smaller than or equal to 2, or page is greater than or equal to 9, then:

```
Me.PageFooter1.Visible = True
Me.PageFooter2.Visible = False
```

Otherwise (so, if page is greater than 2 but less than 9):

```
Me.PageFooter1.Visible = False
Me.PageFooter2.Visible = True
```

That would be reworded as such:

```
 If Me.Page <= 2 Or Me.Page >= 9 Then
     Me.PageFooter1.Visible = True
     Me.PageFooter2.Visible = False
 Else
     Me.PageFooter1.Visible = False
     Me.PageFooter2.Visible = True
 End If
```

But then that still looks weird. Looks like you have 2 "footer styles" going on here. How about introducing that concept?

```
 Dim showFooterStyle1 As Boolean
 showFooterStyle1 = (Me.Page <= 2 Or Me.Page >= 9)

 Me.PageFooter1.Visible = showFooterStyle1
 Me.PageFooter2.Visible = Not showFooterStyle1
```

Now, whether or not that's what you're trying to accomplish is pretty unclear from the question you're asking. But at least it should be easier to see where the problem is.

Comment: The later worked perfectly! I am not sure why I didnt think to Dim the rules. Thank you very much! This will help me a lot in the future!

Comment: one more question; is it possible to use this method when doing a .CAPTION instead of .VISIBLE?

Comment: It works with a single assigment because `Visible` is a `Boolean` - but yes, you could easily use an if/else to set captions based on such rules.